# Airbus pilot Standard call out

Tags: airbus, ecam

For airbus pilots,when they Encounter a Master caution or master warning,what is PF's Standard call out?
"I have a control and communication,ECAM actions.",
OR just "ECAM Actions."?

Answer (score 1):

After having announced the failure it's  ' My Radios, ECAM actions' No need to say 'I have control' if you're the PF!  Other operators SOP's may vary.